# How to get the current time stamp of video being played on my website?

Tags: video, web-deployment

I run face detection and object detection on certain videos and want to build a website to play these videos. During the playing of the videos, I want to show some ads on the webpage based on the detection result above at certain time points of the video, how can I get the current time stamp of the video being played on my website?

Is there any suggestion about which player I might use to play video on my website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get the current time stamp of the video depends on how you implement the video. For example, if you have videos hosted on youtube, you can implement them on your site via the [youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and there are callback functions you can define, using the conventions of the API. Other video frameworks (e.g. [jwplayer](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference), [vimeo](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api)) offer similar APIs.

Or you could just use an [html5 `<video>` tag](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) and look at the `.currentTime` property (put your logic in the `timeupdate` listener).

Which way is best is highly subjective, it's like asking which cell phone carrier you should use.. check them out, see which one fits you best. Most all of them offer the basic functionality you asked about, but maybe one will be better for you as far as hosting options, ease of implementation, etc. Some of them even offer "premium" versions that include showing ads within the player, based on business rules (I know jwplayer does, for example)

Comment: Thanks! The video is hosted on my computer as well as ads. I am new to website development, do you have any recommendation video framework?